# Pass function from parent class to function in child class in React

Tags: reactjs

I am building my first React app, it is a Quiz app. The state of the user's score is incremented by functions in the Parent class. I am having trouble accessing these increment functions from the child class.

I would like to use the increment and decrement functions in the Parent class to update the state of `score`.

My simplified code is below:

**Parent**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0
      };
  }

  increment = () => {
    console.log('+')
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1
    });
  };

  decrement = () => {
    console.log('-')
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score - 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    
    const choice1 = this.state.choice1;
    const choice2 = this.state.choice2;
    const score = this.state.score;
    const correct_answer = this.state.correct_answer;


    return (

          <div>
              <Mybutton 
                text={choice1} 
                score ={score}
                correct_answer={correct_answer} 
                decrement = {this.decrement}
                increment = {this.increment}
                />
          </div>
          
          <div>
              <Mybutton 
                text={choice2} 
                score ={score}
                correct_answer={correct_answer} 
                decrement = {this.decrement}
                increment = {this.increment}
                />
          </div>

      );
    }  
}
```

**Child**

```
class Mybutton extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
    <button onClick={ ()  => {this.handleClick()}}> {this.props.text} </button>
    );
  }

  handleClick(){
    if (this.props.text === this.props.correct_answer){
      this.props.increment
    } else {
      this.props.decrement
    };
  }
```

Comment: Since this.props.increment is a function , you need to call it like ```this.props.increment()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the fuction with prentices `this.props.increment()`